# How can I fade/animate the strokeColor and fillColor of a vector in XML?

Tags: android, colors, selector, animator

I have a RecyclerView with CardViews. The cards have TextViews and ImageButtons, the buttons use vector drawables. I want the cards to fade in/out depending on the enabled state.

I have managed to get the card elevation and textColor to animate using a selector that's set in a style used for the cards, but the same code doesn't seem to work for the strokeColor and fillColor attributes of the vectors. Do they not respect the attributes set by themes, or am I missing something else?

The app is written entirely in Kotlin and using AndroidX/JetPack.

I've played around with animated-vector and animates-selector but I can't get them to work. Do I need separate vector drawables for each color combination I wish to fade between?

The vectors are of the simple type (play button example):

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:strokeWidth="?android:strokeWidth"
        android:pathData="M8,5v14l11,-7z"/>
</vector>
```

They are encapsulated in ImageButtons in the card view layout:

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp" app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_session_play"
    android:id="@+id/playButton" app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/stopButton"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"/>
```

The colors and elevation are then set in a animator selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <item android:state_enabled="true" >
        <objectAnimator android:duration="@integer/enabled_transition_time" >
            <propertyValuesHolder
                    android:propertyName="elevation" android:valueType="floatType"
                    android:valueFrom="@dimen/session_card_disabled_elevation" android:valueTo="@dimen/session_card_enabled_elevation" />
            <propertyValuesHolder
                    android:propertyName="textColor" android:valueType="colorType"
                    android:valueFrom="@color/session_card_disabled_dark" android:valueTo="@color/session_card_enabled_dark" />
            <propertyValuesHolder
                    android:propertyName="fillColor" android:valueType="colorType"
                    android:valueFrom="@color/session_card_disabled_light" android:valueTo="@color/session_card_enabled_light" />
            <propertyValuesHolder
                    android:propertyName="strokeColor" android:valueType="colorType"
                    android:valueFrom="@color/session_card_disabled_dark" android:valueTo="@color/session_card_enabled_dark" />
        </objectAnimator>
    </item>
    <item android:state_enabled="false" >
        <objectAnimator android:duration="@integer/enabled_transition_time" >
            <propertyValuesHolder
                    android:propertyName="elevation" android:valueType="floatType"
                    android:valueFrom="@dimen/session_card_enabled_elevation" android:valueTo="@dimen/session_card_disabled_elevation" />
            <propertyValuesHolder
                    android:propertyName="textColor" android:valueType="colorType"
                    android:valueFrom="@color/session_card_enabled_dark" android:valueTo="@color/session_card_disabled_dark" />
            <propertyValuesHolder
                    android:propertyName="fillColor" android:valueType="colorType"
                    android:valueFrom="@color/session_card_enabled_light" android:valueTo="@color/session_card_disabled_light" />
            <propertyValuesHolder
                    android:propertyName="strokeColor" android:valueType="colorType"
                    android:valueFrom="@color/session_card_enabled_dark" android:valueTo="@color/session_card_disabled_dark" />
        </objectAnimator>
    </item>
</selector>
```

and finally, this is referenced in the style declaration:

```
<style name="SessionCardStyle" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:stateListAnimator">@animator/session_card_enable_disable</item>
    <item name="android:strokeWidth">1</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I figured it out... the CardView will animate certain values by itself. All I had to do was to move the color values out to my styles.xml:

```
    <style name="SessionCardStyle" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:stateListAnimator">@animator/session_card_enable_disable</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/session_card_darks</item>
        <item name="android:fillColor">@color/session_card_lights</item>
        <item name="android:strokeColor">@color/session_card_darks</item>
        <item name="android:strokeWidth">1</item>
    </style>
```

And them have selectors for the colors based on enabled state (this is res/color/session_card_darks.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_enabled="true"  android:color="#FF000000" />
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="#40000000" />
</selector>
```

And finally take away all those colors from the animator:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_enabled="true" >
        <objectAnimator android:propertyName="elevation" android:valueType="floatType" android:valueTo="@dimen/session_card_enabled_elevation" />
    </item>
    <item android:state_enabled="false" >
        <objectAnimator android:propertyName="elevation" android:valueType="floatType" android:valueTo="@dimen/session_card_disabled_elevation" />
    </item>
</selector>
```

Still, if anybody knows how to have selectors for dimensions directly, this could be even smaller.